# What does 「という事になっている」mean in this context?

Tags: grammar

> 小説の博士が愛したのは、オイラーの公式、e(pi i) + 1 = 0 ということになっている。

How is this 「という事になっている」in this context generally used? Is there an approximate translation that works here?

Comment: +1 for mentioning Euler's wonderful equation!!!

Comment: Since I'm not entirely sure, I'll not post this as an answer.  But, I would move the grammar about when translating into English, "The professor came  around to loving Euler's Equation $e^{\pi i}+1=0$".

Comment: 「小説の」とあるので、フィクションだから、「～という設定になっている」っていう意味じゃないですかね。。。

Answer (score 4):

～という事になっている　means the things are known as ～ in general or among people and including the nuance like "but it isn't sure".

For example, 私は友達の間で日本人という事になっているが、本当は中国人だ。(I am known as Japanese among my friends but I am Chinese.)

Answer (score 4):

> 「[小説]{しょうせつ}の[博士]{はかせ}が[愛]{あい}したのは、オイラーの[公式]{こうしき}、e(pi i) + 1 = 0 **ということになっている**。」

「～～ということになっている」, in this context, means that the ~~ part describes the "***fact***" that has been ***set up for the novel by its author***.

In this case, one of those "facts" is that the doctor loved that formula by Euler.

The 「と」 in 「**と**いうこと」 is quotative.