# Understanding ことになっている

Tags: grammar

> この施設の出入口は、天宮市の一角に建った雑居ビルの中にあるため、比較的気軽に外に出ることが可能なのである。
>
> まあ、無論一般市民に<ラタトスク>のことを知られるわけにはいかないため、そのビルの中には適当な会社が入っている**ことになっている**し、中津川たちも今は<ラタトスク>の制服ではなく、会社員然としたビジネススーツの上にコートを羽織り、ついでに首から社員証を下げていた。この姿を見て彼らを秘匿組織の一員だと思う者はまずいないだろう。

Context: <ラタトスク> is a 秘匿組織.

Question: How should I understand the bold ことになっている? My grammar book says it refers to some rule, law or discipline, etc. But this 「ことになっている」doesn’t mean that in the context.

Or does it just mean “a decision was made some time ago”, as explained in this thread?

> 「ことになっています」 means that the decision/plan/rule was made some time (or a
> long time) ago. The news is no longer new to the speaker and s/he is
> more "ready" for the event.

[https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57863/ことになった-vs-ことになっている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57863/%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F-vs-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B)

Comment: Not exactly the same, but  does this help you understand the situation a little better?https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/51701/22352

Comment: [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32387/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38320/5010) are related, but this may be the first time this construction was directly asked...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ことにする has several meanings, one of which is "to pretend". Likewise, ことになっている can sometimes mean "it is supposed that ～ (although that's not true)", "(externally) it is believed that ～".

- 見なかったことにしよう。
  Let's pretend we didn't see it.
- 彼はここに来なかったことにしておけ。
  Pretend he never came here.
- 私は10年前に死んだことになっている。
  I'm supposed to have died 10 years ago.
  <sub>(This tends to be used when someone intentionally set up his pretended death. Compare 私は10年前に死んだと思われている, which implies nothing about the cause.)</sub>
- そのビルの中には適当な会社が入っていることになっている。
  The building is supposed to have some random companies in it.
  <sub>(This clearly means the true nature of the building is disguised.)</sub>

Here's 明鏡国語辞典's definition regarding ことにする.

> ① ある動作・行為が自分の意志で決めたものである意を表す。…こととする。「旅行は一人で行く━・した」
> ②《「…た━」の形で》**事実に反して（都合よく）、そのように決める（みなす）意を表す。「このことは見なかった━」**
> ③《「━・している」の形で》意志的な行為が自然に習慣化したものである意を表す。「家では仕事の話はしない━・している」

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a small question. Since the ことになっている is used in the sense of “to pretend”, why isn’t 入っていたことになっている used? The dictionary says we should use た form before ことになっている for that meaning.

Comment: @chinoalpha ていることにする and ていることになっている are also perfectly fine, and the dictionary have failed to mention this. 来なかったことにしておけ and 来ていないことにしておけ are usually interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you again. I see. So can we use 入っていたことになっている or 入ったことになっている in this context?

Comment: @chinoalpha 入っていたことになっている means those companies are already gone now. Just apply the usual rule regarding tense/aspect you already know.

Comment: Thank you. So does 入ったことになっている work in this context? If it doesn’t, it also means those companies are already gone now?

Comment: @chinoalpha When the focus is what's in the building *now*, ビルに会社が入った is highly unnatural. You need to say ビルに会社が入っている.

Comment: Oh. I see. Much appreciated.